# Subsonic Delete multiple records

Tags: subsonic

I have a table which has a two fields, userid and degreeid. A user can have multiple degreeds in this table. When a user select their degree I want to delete any degree id already in the database but un-selected by user. How should do it? I try to use something like this with no luck.

repo.DeleteMany(x=>x.MeetingAttendeeUserID==userID && x.EducationDegreeID userDegreeList)

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this?

```
repo.DeleteMany(x =>
    x.MeetingAttendeeUserId == userID &&
    x.EducationDegreeID != selectedDegreeId
);
```

Edit: Or this.

```
repo.DeleteMany(x =>
    x.MeetingAttendeeUserId == userID &&
    userDegreeList.Contains(x.EducationDegreeID))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried

```
SubSonicRepository<ReportDatum> repo = new SubSonicRepository<ReportDatum>(db);
repo.DeleteMany(x => x.ReportID == Convert.ToInt32(reportID));
```

and it does nothing, not even an error.

Addendum for someone that comes across this:
don't convert in the delete call, convert your variables beforehand.

```
int deleteKey = Convert.ToInt32(reportID)
SubSonicRepository<ReportDatum> repo = new SubSonicRepository<ReportDatum>(db);
repo.DeleteMany(x => x.ReportID == deleteKey);
```

and it fired fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if you dont know Lamda expression. Create your own stored procedure and call use it.

This will not restrict you using lamda expression if you don't have time to learn it.

Ultimately you wanted to done your job.